# Classification After Cropping

Tags: java, android, image-classification

I did object detection. I cropped the detected object. Now i need to classify this cropped image. I followed this tutorial for classification. https://www.kaggle.com/code/kmkarakaya/transfer-learning-for-image-classification.

my report results: I have two classes: EveningTray and BreakfastTray

[image: result]

I converted this model to .tflite. on android the result is always 100% eveningTray. I am missing this part.

```
public class TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel implements ClassifierTwo {
    private static final String TAG = "TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModelWithInterpreter";

    private static final int NUM_DETECTIONS = 10;
    private static final float IMAGE_MEAN = 127.5f;
    private static final float IMAGE_STD = 127.5f;
    private static final int NUM_THREADS = 4;
    private boolean isModelQuantized;

    private int inputSize;

    private final List<String> labels = new ArrayList<>();
    private int[] intValues;

    private float[][][] outputLocations;
    private float[][] outputClasses;

    private float[][] outputScores;
    private float[] numDetections;

    private ByteBuffer imgData;

    private MappedByteBuffer tfLiteModel;
    private Interpreter.Options tfLiteOptions;
    private Interpreter tfLite;

    private float[][] foodMap;
    private static final int FOOD_SIZE = 2;
    private static final float WHITE_THRESH = 255f;

    private TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel() {}
    /** Memory-map the model file in Assets. */
    private static MappedByteBuffer loadModelFile(AssetManager assets, String modelFilename)
            throws IOException {
        AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = assets.openFd(modelFilename);
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());
        FileChannel fileChannel = inputStream.getChannel();
        long startOffset = fileDescriptor.getStartOffset();
        long declaredLength = fileDescriptor.getDeclaredLength();
        return fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, startOffset, declaredLength);
    }
    public static ClassifierTwo create(
            final Context context,
            final String modelFilename,
            final String labelFilename,
            final int inputSize,
            final boolean isQuantized)
            throws IOException {
        final TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel d = new TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel();

        AssetManager am = context.getAssets();
        InputStream is = am.open(labelFilename);

        MappedByteBuffer modelFile = loadModelFile(context.getAssets(), modelFilename);
        MetadataExtractor metadata = new MetadataExtractor(modelFile);
        try (BufferedReader br =
                     new BufferedReader(
                             new InputStreamReader(is))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                //Log.w(TAG, line);
                d.labels.add(line);
            }
        }

        d.inputSize = inputSize;

        try {
            Interpreter.Options options = new Interpreter.Options();
            options.setNumThreads(NUM_THREADS);
            options.setUseXNNPACK(true);
            d.tfLite = new Interpreter(modelFile, options);
            d.tfLiteModel = modelFile;
            d.tfLiteOptions = options;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        d.isModelQuantized = isQuantized;
        // Pre-allocate buffers.
        int numBytesPerChannel;
        if (isQuantized) {
            numBytesPerChannel = 1; // Quantized
        } else {
            numBytesPerChannel = 4; // Floating point
        }
        d.imgData = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1 * d.inputSize * d.inputSize * 3 * numBytesPerChannel);
        d.imgData.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        d.intValues = new int[d.inputSize * d.inputSize];

        d.outputLocations = new float[1][NUM_DETECTIONS][2];
        d.outputClasses = new float[1][NUM_DETECTIONS];
        d.outputScores = new float[1][NUM_DETECTIONS];
        d.numDetections = new float[1];
        return d;
    }

    @Override
    public String recognizeImage1(final Bitmap bitmap) {
        // Log this method so that it can be analyzed with systrace.
        Trace.beginSection("recognizeImage1");

        Trace.beginSection("preprocessBitmap");
        // Preprocess the image data from 0-255 int to normalized float based
        // on the provided parameters.
        bitmap.getPixels(intValues, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

        imgData.rewind();
        for (int i = 0; i < inputSize; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < inputSize; ++j) {
                int pixelValue = intValues[i * inputSize + j];


                if (isModelQuantized) {
                    // Quantized model
                    imgData.put((byte) ((pixelValue >> 16) & 0xFF));
                    imgData.put((byte) ((pixelValue >> 8) & 0xFF));
                    imgData.put((byte) (pixelValue & 0xFF));
                } else {
                    imgData.putFloat((pixelValue & 0xFF) / WHITE_THRESH);
                    imgData.putFloat(((pixelValue >> 8) & 0xFF) / WHITE_THRESH);
                    imgData.putFloat(((pixelValue >> 16) & 0xFF) / WHITE_THRESH);
                }
            }
        }


        Trace.endSection();
        // Copy the input data into TensorFlow.
        Trace.beginSection("feed");


        Object[] inputArray = {imgData};

        Map<Integer, Object> outputMap = new HashMap<>();

        foodMap = new float[1][FOOD_SIZE];



        outputMap.put(0, foodMap);
        Trace.endSection();

        // Run the inference call.
        Trace.beginSection("run");


        tfLite.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(inputArray, outputMap);


        Log.w("traytype", "!!!traytype: " + foodMap[0][0] + "|" + foodMap[0][1] );

        Integer foodInd = 0;
 
        Float max = -1f;
        for (int i = 0; i < foodMap[0].length; i++) {
            float currValue = foodMap[0][i];

            if (currValue > max) {
                max = currValue;
                foodInd = i;
            }

        }






        List<String> foodList = Arrays.asList("eveningTray", "breakfastTray");


        String label = "traytype: " + foodList.get(foodInd);

        Trace.endSection();

        final int numDetectionsOutput = 1;
        final ArrayList<Recognition> recognitions = new ArrayList<>(numDetectionsOutput);



        Trace.endSection();
        return label;
    }
//    @Override
//    public List<Recognition> recognizeImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
//        return null;
//    }



    @Override
    public void enableStatLogging(boolean debug) {

    }

    @Override
    public String getStatString() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        if (tfLite != null) {
            tfLite.close();
            tfLite = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setNumThreads(int num_threads) {
        if (tfLite != null) {
            tfLiteOptions.setNumThreads(num_threads);
            recreateInterpreter();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setUseNNAPI(boolean isChecked) {
        if (tfLite != null) {
            tfLiteOptions.setUseNNAPI(isChecked);
            recreateInterpreter();
        }
    }

    private void recreateInterpreter() {
        tfLite.close();
        tfLite = new Interpreter(tfLiteModel, tfLiteOptions);
    }

    @Override
    public float getObjThresh() {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

I followed here for classification in android:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZepT3N6aNFM&t=881s

update:
The problem may be  the model.

Comment: Does it work on the same images without tflite?

Comment: Yes,  I will test it again and add it to the question.

Comment: Hi, @dan1st I followed here :https://keras.io/examples/vision/image_classification_efficientnet_fine_tuning/ AND https://github.com/vatsaldpatel/EfficientNet-Transfer-Learning/blob/master/transfer_learning_EfficientNet.py this is mine: https://github.com/usertttwm/EfficientNetImageClassification/blob/main/dinnerTrayBreakfastTrayImageClassification.ipynb
additionally I used callback for best model. and I printed the classification report. the result is always 1.00 overfitting? Do you have an idea ? Is there anything I missed? Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you get that result on the training or on a distinct test set? Where are you evaluating it?

Comment: I used the test folder for the classification report @dan1st